# UITextField on iOS and Sparrow Framework

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, keyboard, uikit, sparrow-framework

I need to have a UITextField programmatically added on a UIView. I don't even need the UITextField to be visible, only the keyboard, since I intend to handle the textfield aspect elsehow. However the keyboard doesn't show up at all.

I have this:

```
UITextField* field = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];

SPView* view = (SPView*)[SPStage mainStage].nativeView; // I think I don't need this line I believe, since I don't need it visible, but this is my UIView (SPView inherits from UIView)
[view addSubview:field];

[field becomeFirstResponder];
```

Should I need anything more to show up a iOS native keyboard?

Why can't be the keyboard showing up? Am I missing something important?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. I was calling the code in the constructor.

While everything else on Sparrow can be done in the constructor, the nativeView doesn't get assigned until after everything is constructed, so the view was giving `(null)` on an `NSLog(@"%@", view);`

Made a delayed call to the code (waiting 0.2 seconds before calling it) and now it works perfectly.